# Despite Selenium WebDriver only parts of the page are being parsed

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to extract data from a website using BeautifulSoup and Selenium, as the website has a lot of dynamic content. Although I use Selenium to simulate a webdriver it returns the same amount of results as it does with BeautifulSoup only. The len(container) should be equal to 20, however, it returns 4 all the time. I am not sure what I am doing wrong, or how to solve the issue. Below is my code:

```
import bs4
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'https://www.immowelt.at/liste/wien/wohnungen/mieten?eqid=1011&cp=1'

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--blink-settings=imagesEnabled=false')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Users\xxx\chromedriver')
driver.get(url)
html = driver.page_source
page_soup = soup(html, 'html.parser')

container = page_soup.findAll('div', class_='listcontent clear')
print(len(container))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page is loading the items dynamically via JavaScript. You can use this script to load all (264 items):

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.immowelt.at/liste/wien/wohnungen/mieten?eqid=1011&cp=1'
api_url = 'https://www.immowelt.at/liste/getlistitems'

offset, pagesize = 0, 4
with requests.session() as s:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get(url).content, 'html.parser')
    query = soup.select_one('#filterView')['value']
    total = int(soup.h1.text.split()[0])

    all_data = ''
    while offset < total:
        print('Offset {}...'.format(offset))
        data = {'query': query,
                'offset': offset,
                'pageSize': pagesize}
        all_data += s.post(api_url, data=data).text

        offset += pagesize

soup = BeautifulSoup(all_data, 'html.parser')

for item in soup.select('.listitem'):
    print(item.h2.get_text(strip=True))
    print(item.select_one('.price_rent').get_text(strip=True, separator=' '))
    print('-' * 80)

print('Total: ', len(soup.select('.listitem')))
```

Prints:

```
...

NEUES WOHNJUWEL FÜR STUDIERENDE
Gesamtmiete 850 €
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DACHGESCHOSSLOFT FÜR STUDIERENDE
Gesamtmiete 750 €
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
NEUES WOHNJUWEL FÜR STUDIERENDE
Gesamtmiete 750 €
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Toplage in Mauer
Gesamtmiete 995,50 €
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total:  264
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Your code is Fine. This is just bad programming by the web developer.

inside  this <'div', class_='listcontent clear'> there are only 4 elements, rest 16 are in a diffrent div all together

you can verify this using the below xpath >> returns 4 matches only
/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[5]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div

use this instead and filter accordingly
container = page_soup.findAll('div', class_='js-object   listitem_wrap')
```